# mysql after insert trigger which updates another table's column

Tags: mysql, sql-update, triggers

i'm trying to write a trigger, I have following tables:
  BookingRequest:

```
  +-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | idRequest | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | roomClass | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | inDate    | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | outDate   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | numOfBeds | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | status    | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | idUser    | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    +-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

status table:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                                             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idStatus   | int(11)                                          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| nameStatus | enum('underConsideration','approved','rejected') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

OccupiedRoom:

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idOccupation | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idRoom       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| idRequest    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

i need a trigger which will change status in BookingReques to 1 if request with the same id is inserted into OccupiedRoom table, so i tried something like this

```
create trigger occupy_trig after insert on OccupiedRoom 
for each row
begin
  if BookingRequest.idRequest= NEW.idRequest
   then
       update BookingRequest
       set status = '1';
       where idRequest = NEW.idRequest;

    end if;
END;
```

and it doesn't work, so any suggestions would be very appriciated

Comment: removing the semi-colon after `set status ='1'` should do it

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER occupy_trig
AFTER INSERT ON `OccupiedRoom` FOR EACH ROW
begin
       DECLARE id_exists Boolean;
       -- Check BookingRequest table
       SELECT 1
       INTO @id_exists
       FROM BookingRequest
       WHERE BookingRequest.idRequest= NEW.idRequest;

       IF @id_exists = 1
       THEN
           UPDATE BookingRequest
           SET status = '1'
           WHERE idRequest = NEW.idRequest;
        END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This answer is the best answer I've ever found on Stack Overflow for my problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 48):

With your requirements you don't need `BEGIN END` and `IF` with unnecessary `SELECT` in your trigger. So you can simplify it to this

```
CREATE TRIGGER occupy_trig AFTER INSERT ON occupiedroom 
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE BookingRequest
     SET status = 1
   WHERE idRequest = NEW.idRequest;
```

Comment: @DeadKennedy Why don't you make it as the accepted answer? It'll help others to look at this answer.

Comment: Yup, this should be the accepted answer, in my opinion.

Comment: I have a syntax error when I try using this code on the WHERE line:

`drop trigger if exists actualizaDataApto;
CREATE TRIGGER actualizaDataApto AFTER INSERT ON doacao 
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE doador
     SET Data_Apto = DATE_ADD(Data_Apto, INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
   WHERE doador.id_Doador = NEW.Doador_id_Doador;`

Could you please help me?

Comment: @C.Rib Comments section is not a good place for this. Please post a proper question and  I or other SO members will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe remove the semi-colon after set because now the where statement doesn't belong to the update statement. Also the `idRequest` could be a problem, better write `BookingRequest.idRequest`

Comment: You can't change it's value in `AFTER` trigger. But you can still use it to update another table.

Answer (score -3):

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER contacts_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON contacts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE vUser varchar(50);

   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into table
   SELECT USER() INTO vUser;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO contacts_audit
   ( contact_id,
     deleted_date,
     deleted_by)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.contact_id,
     SYSDATE(),
     vUser );

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```