# Does this SQL trigger accomplish its objective?

Tags: sql, triggers

Before anything else:

- The asterisked attributes in the relational database schema code below are primary keys
- Stores with the same name but different sID (and address) form what we call a store chain
- Purchase entity set contains every transaction (tID) which corresponds to one customer (cID) who buys from one store (sID) on one date (date)
- Two stores are considered to be different when they have a different store IDs

The subjected relational schema:

```
customer (cID*, cName, street, city):
store (sID*, sName, street, city)
product (pID*, pName, suffix)
shoppinglist (cID*, pID*, quantity, date)
purchase (tID*, cID, sID, pID*, date, quantity, price)
inventory (sID, pID, date, quantity, unit-price)
```

I provided myself with the following objective: to write a trigger that, for each purchase, subtracts the quantity from the inventory of the store where the purchase was made. In order to don't overkill the outlined context I will assume that the customers cannot purchase more than the store's inventory contains at that moment.

The SQL code I came up with looks as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER substracting_from_store_stock_with_the_client_demand 
AFTER INSERT ON purchase
referencing new row as nrow
when for each nrow.quantity > 0
begin
    update inventory
    set inventory.quantity = inventory.quantity - nrow.quantity
    where inventory.sID = nrow.sID 
      and inventory.pID = nrow.pID
end
```

**The question**

Do you see a more "elegant" and "efficient" way in which this trigger could have been written?

PS: if by coincidence you remark any mistake or disrupted area in the previous code don't retain yourself from pointing the issues out.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: 1) this code would not run in mysql. What database product do you use? 2) define what you mean by more efficient and more elegant? Are there any performance botlenecks you experience with it?

Comment: hi there. 1) I'm aware of that. Unfortunately, I have no setup at my disposal such that to undertake several tests across multiples database products and answer you specifically. I laid it down on a piece of paper. 2) No. There's no specific requirement to be fulfilled - apart from the one that implies the overall objective which must be achieved. I asked that out from curiosity, in the attempt to refine my way of writing triggers.

Comment: so its not MSSQL. its for MySQL. please check this url it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994206/mysql-triggers-and-referencing

Comment: The syntax corresponds to the SQL Standard since 99`.

Comment: 1) I'm glad you are aware this syntax does not work with mysql. Then why did you tag your question as mysql?  2) thus trigger is pretty much as simple as it can get, so not much you can do with it. Particularly not from a performance point of view as that would require knowing the exact database product.

Comment: 1) I thought that this way I will widen the scope of audience, increasing the chance to be given with multiple answers I could choose amongst. 2) Not pretty sure that for this basic level knowing exactly how the subjected database looks would come as an indispensable information. However, if there's further need for information regarding to the presented schema, I'll be glad to diminish the confusion by sharing some more thoughtful insights.

Comment: "the SQL Standard since 99" doesn't help you, as no product follows it properly. Use the syntax corresponding with the actual product you are using, which you still haven't made clear which it is.