# Triggers with select case mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to triggers and select case.
This is my first attempt. 
What I trying to do is, everytime a new row is entered in the `rawdata` table, the trigger should check for the name that was inserted in `rawdata` table. If that name doesn't appear in the `stateDetails` table, then insert another row in the `stateDetails` table with state = 'New ID' with that name.
It gives me syntax errors.

Thanks

This is what I have tried

```
create trigger rawDataTrigger after insert on rawData
 for each row
BEGIN
 set @sID= (Select `Name` from rawdata where name not like '')
 set @checkID = (select `Name` from stateDetails where name = @sID)
 Select Case  
  when @checkID= null then
  (
    Insert into stateDetails (`sID`,`State`) VALUES (@sID,'new ID')
  )
  end
```

Comment: @sID should be New.Name. Get rid of the single quotes around the right hand side of your set statements.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson what do you mean by New.Name?

Comment: The records being inserted or have just have been inserted are in a pseudo table called New.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sorry can you give an example. I am `New` to this.. :)

Comment: See the answer to this question for an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Let me take a look.. Thanks..

Comment: If it was a before insert query, the data wouldn't be in the table you hadn't yet inserted to...

Comment: what I am trying to do is.... If the data doesn't exist in the stateDetails table, then insert it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thanks for the link. The link is helpful.. Let me try that and get back to you.