# MySQL - Elegant Sum

Tags: mysql, sum

I am looking for an elegant solution to a seemingly simple MySQL problem:

I've got a table with soccer teams and game results from a soccer league.

```
league  day  team1   team2      points1    points2
bl0910  1    munich  hamburg    3          0
bl0910  1    bremen  stuttgart  1          1
...
```

Now I want to add a column, where all points of a team from all previous game days are summed up.

Like:

```
league  day  team1   team2      points1    points2   sum1    sum2
...
bl0910  8    bremen  hamburg    1          1         11      15
bl0910  8    munich  stuttgart  0          3         16      9
...
```

Is it possible with some elegant syntax, or do I have to use cursors and a temporary table?

Kind Regards
Theo

Comment: I'd need bigger data sample to check expected results.

Comment: Use [Triger after insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column).

Comment: I wouldn't store derived data in a table. Create the sums when you query it.  If you *really* need a query you'll have to use a sub-subselect to get around the restrictions with INSERT-SELECT