# Create a Trigger in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger on one of the Table, lets say AssetDataTable In which the values gets populated via a Windows service, so basically I want to do is

```
SELECT * FROM AssetDataTable Where AssetID = 105 ORDER by 1 DESC;
```

I get this one row back,
Now if any of the column value is zero, it should update in another StatusTable

```
AssetID   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
 105      18.8      19.9     13.0     18.7     0
```

Now In My StatusTable, the row should become

```
       AssetID  Status 
         105     0
```

I really don't have any clue how to do, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example this is the guidelines for your desired result i hope this may helps you

```
DELIMITER //

 CREATE TRIGGER contacts_after_update
 AFTER UPDATE
 ON contacts FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN

  DECLARE vUser varchar(50);
```

-- Find username of person performing the INSERT into table

```
  SELECT USER() INTO vUser;
```

-- Insert record into audit table

```
  INSERT INTO contacts_audit
   (   contact_id,
   updated_date,
   updated_by)
   VALUES
   (  NEW.contact_id,
  SYSDATE(),
  vUser );

 END; //

 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you can refer this you get valuable information......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column