# When I insert a row, update a column in a different table

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL to create some kind of rule for a table that when I insert a new row into that table, that it updates a column in a separate table?

Thank you!

Comment: you are looking for triggers

Comment: You can create a trigger to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql after insert trigger which updates another table's column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use trigger.You can create trigger insert on table and updated value to second table.

More details for trigger refer this link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **AFTER INSERT Trigger** for the table in which new rows being inserted.

You can check the after insert trigger here:[Link](http://mysql%20after%20insert%20trigger%20which%20updates%20another%20table's%20column)