# Update where associated table has specific value on column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: houses and users

`houses` has a foreign key to user via the column `user_id`. It has also a column called active which is either 'yes' or 'no'

`users` has a column called active which is either 'yes' or 'no'

I want to run a query to update all the houses active column to be 'no' as long as their associated user has 'no' in its active column AND the house active column is not already 'no'.

I know how to update based on the users table value, but I don't know how to do it when the conditions are on both an associated table and its own table.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you would do:

```
update houses h
    set active = 'no'
    from users u
    where h.user_id = u.user_id and h.active <> 'no' and u.active = 'no';
```

Note that `<> 'no'` should perhaps be `is distinct from 'no'`, if you want to take `NULL` values into account.

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
update a 
set field x = case when fieldy = somecondition then A else fieldy end
from table1 a join table2 b on a.someid=b.someid
```

Comment: Do **not** repeat the target table in the `FROM` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can inner join the two tables and then update house activity based on the two conditions.

```
    update t1
    set t1.active = 'no'
    from house t1
    inner join users t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    where t2.active = 'no'
    and not t1.active = 'no'
```

Comment: do **not** repeat the target table in the  `FROM` clause

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a trigger, so whenever you execute an update on the users '`active`' column, it will trigger and update the houses table.

Take a look on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16892291/2469264)