# Result of query as column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got three tables:

Lessons:

```
CREATE TABLE lessons (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    vocab_count integer NOT NULL
);

+----+------------+------------------+-------------+
| id |   title    |   description    | vocab_count |
+----+------------+------------------+-------------+
|  1 | lesson_one | this is a lesson |           3 |
|  2 | lesson_two | another lesson   |           2 |
+----+------------+------------------+-------------+
```

Lesson_vocabulary:

```
CREATE TABLE lesson_vocabulary (
    lesson_id integer REFERENCES lessons(id),
    vocabulary_id integer REFERENCES vocabulary(id)
);

+-----------+---------------+
| lesson_id | vocabulary_id |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 |             1 |
|         1 |             2 |
|         1 |             3 |
|         2 |             2 |
|         2 |             4 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Vocabulary:

```
CREATE TABLE vocabulary (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    hiragana text NOT NULL,
    reading text NOT NULL,
    meaning text[] NOT NULL
);
```

Each lesson contains multiple vocabulary, and each vocabulary can be included in multiple lessons.

How can I get the vocab_count column of the lessons table to be calculated and updated whenevr I add more rows to the lesson_vocabulary table. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You need a trigger for that. But in general you shouldn't store information in a relational database that can be derived from existing data. Why not create a view that returns that count?

Comment: Right, I see your point. So I shouldn't create a column for this at all, and just create a view which displays all the linked vocabulary for each lesson?

Comment: Also, so if I want to display the lesson information including the vocabulary_count of each lesson on a page. Would I first fetch all of the rows in the lessons table, and then run a query for each one to calculate the vocabulary_count myself? Is there a way I can do it in one step?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL triggers to serve your purpose. This would be similar to [mysql after insert trigger which updates another table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892070/mysql-after-insert-trigger-which-updates-another-tables-column).

The trigger would look somewhat like this. I am using Oracle SQL, but there would just be minor tweaks for any other implementation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER vocab_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON lesson_vocabulary
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
   for lesson_cur in (select LESSON_ID, COUNT(VOCABULARY_ID) voc_cnt from LESSON_VOCABULARY group by LESSON_ID) LOOP
   update LESSONS
       set VOCAB_COUNT = LESSON_CUR.VOC_CNT
       where id = LESSON_CUR.LESSON_ID;
  end loop; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a view that calculates that (and get rid of the column in the lessons table):

```
select l.*, lv.vocab_count
from lessons l 
  left join (
    select lesson_id, count(*)
    from lesson_vocabulary
    group by lesson_id
  ) as lv(lesson_id, vocab_count) on l.id = lv.lesson_id
```

---

If you really want to update the lessons table each time the lesson_vocabulary changes, you can run an UPDATE statement like this in a trigger:

```
update lessons l
  set vocab_count = t.cnt
from (
  select lesson_id, count(*) as cnt
  from lesson_vocabulary
  group by lesson_id
) t
where t.lesson_id = l.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a query for this information:

```
select l.*,
       (select count(*)
        from lesson_vocabulary lv
        where lv.lesson_id = l.lesson_id
       ) as vocabulary_cnt
from lessons l;
```

With an index on `lesson_vocabulary(lesson_id)`, this should be quite fast.

I recommend this over an `update`, because the data remains correct.

I recommend this over a trigger, because it is simpler.

I recommend this over a subquery with aggregation because it should be faster, particularly if you are filtering on the `lessons` table.

Comment: In my experience the join against the derived table isn't really slower and filter conditions are happily pushed down by Postgres. The co-related subquery tends to be slower if you do that for many rows though. The more rows (from the lesson table) it has to process the bigger the difference gets

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Not if you are selecting all the rows in the first table.  However, if the rows are filtered in the outer query, then I don't think Postgres pushes the filtering to the aggregation subquery, so the aggregation is doing much more work.

Comment: Postgres does push down the filter expression: [plan for derived table](https://explain.depesz.com/s/Z3f) [plan for scalar sub-query](https://explain.depesz.com/s/jA9C)  (100.000 rows lessons, 1 million rows in lesson_vocabulary)